# Flex Result event... question

Tags: php, xml, apache-flex

On ResultEvent through HTTPService, i need to print the result in a textBox.

private function google(evt:ResultEvent):void
    {

```
Alert.show(evt.result.loginsuccess.person);

subtitle.text = evt.result.loginsuccess.person.keyword;

    }
```

This is my XML coming down from PHP file... [index.php]

```
<loginsuccess><person><keyword>java</keyword><name>http://www.xml.com/</name><occur>4</occur></person
><person><keyword>java</keyword><name>http://www.sitepoint.com</name><occur>2</occur></person><person
><keyword>java</keyword><name>http://www.httpguru.com</name><occur>2</occur></person></loginsuccess>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as the above answer but if you wish to get a specific value you can do evt.result.person.keyword[0] (this will give you the first value).
Someone else's answer would give you the XML 3 times, but specifying which keyword node you wish to get will return just the value inside that node (i.e. 'java')

as an aside I've just had a look at your profile, do you know that after you've asked a question and then liked one of the answers you can mark that answer as correct. None of the 9 question with 30+ answers you've asked have been flagged as answered, has nobody answered any of your questions appropriately!

Comment: I dont get the perfect riposte sometimes, i am new as in other communities i don't mark as you said.

Comment: Alert.show(event.result.person.keyword[0]);

I am not getting an alert itself, for the above one.

Comment: it should work, I copied your XML from above and did the following just to make sure I was right.

var xml : XML = new XML('<loginsuccess><person><keyword>java</keyword><name>http://www.xml.com/</name><occur>4</occur></person><person><keyword>java</keyword><name>http://www.sitepoint.com</name><occur>2</occur></person><person><keyword>java</keyword><name>http://www.httpguru.com</name><occur>2</occur></person></loginsuccess>');
ta.text = xml.person.keyword[0];//ta is just a textArea.

Comment: Have specified the result format (resultFormat="e4x") inside your httpService?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to reference the top level node in the XML.
So if you do evt.result.person.keyword; then that will display the 3 results.

Comment: ?is it actually reaching the result handler?
If the XML that is coming back isn't properly formatted it will end up in the faulthandler (I take it you set up a faultHandler - if not set it up).  Once the result & faulthanders are both set up put in a breakpoint for each function that way it will come back and hit at least one of the functions and you can take it from there.